# Strip all HTML code from String with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, strip-tags

I am currently pulling some data from a SQL Server database into a C# asp.net page.

I am using the following (portion of) code to ouput the HTML text that is stored in my `body` column:

```
TextLabel.Text += "<div class=\"newsEntry\">" + 
    Convert.ToString(reader2["body"]).Substring(0, 220) + 
    "...<a href='entry.aspx?ID=" + reader2["ID"] + 
    "' title=\"Read More about " + reader2["Title"] + 
    "\">Read More &raquo;</a></div>";
```

I'd like to strip the body value (`+ Convert.ToString(reader2["body"]).Substring(0, 220) +`) of all HTML inside it.

**How do I achieve this with C#?**

Normally with PHP, I'd use `striptags`.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` do totally different things. Make up your mind.

Comment: I've just made it up. I'd like to strip all the HTML inside `body` :) Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do with parsing HTML in C#, look first to the HTML Agility Pack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you are always using "<div class=\"newsEntry\">" this you can use simply split function. Otherwise if your body has html tags you can use agilitypack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx) and [HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode.aspx) methods

Comment: it will code and decode html characters like "<" to "&lt;" what is the relation of it in striping.

Comment: Aaaah great. So on entry ENCODE and on output DECODE? :)